# Object calls vs internal database statements

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, object

I have an android app and it I want it to display a set of questions dynamically.
To help me do this, I have an external database(outside the app) and an internal database(SQLite inside the app). I copy the external to the internal database.

The database contains Surveys, with an x amount of questions.

My question is, is it better to display the questions through frequent statements from the internal database, or make a single statement from the internal database and parse the data into a Survey object and display the questions by talking to the Survey object?

The reason why I ask is because passing an object from Activity to Activity in android isn't easily done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing something similar, and the things that I do to make this easier are:

- When I receive the information about a survey as JSON from the back-end API, instead of de-serializing the JSON, I just store the entire JSON in the database as a string.
- In the survey Activity, I get the JSON from the local SQLite database, and deserialize it (using GSON). Having it as a String here instead of (or in addition to) a graph of objects means that I can easily save it in a Bundle, or pass it in an Intent if I need to.
- I use a single Activity for the survey, and Fragments to show the individual questions. But again, if you have the survey info as a JSON string, you can keep your individual Activities, and pass the survey data between them via the Intent extras.

The 'downside' of this approach is that you may need to frequently deserialize the same data, but I think that this is better than frequently querying the database, and is typically lightweight enough to be done on the main thread without affecting the UI performance. And it means that you don't have to deal with Parcelable.